# Uploaded images in shows in excluded format in asp.net webapi

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

i have written code for uploading profile image , but after uploading files it gets excluded format in my uploaded folder. How could include this or do you have any other solution to upload file?

```
     $("#btnUploadFile").click(function (evt) {
            alert('dfdfd');

            var imgup = 'img';
            var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                var data = new FormData();
                for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    data.append("file" + i, files[i]);

                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/api/EmployeeMasterApi/UploadFile/'+'?imgup' + imgup,

                    contentType: false,

                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                   // data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (messages) {
                        for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                            alert('dddd');
                            alert(messages[i]);

                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error while invoking the Web API");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

i used below code for file upload in c#. side

```
       [HttpPost]
            public void UploadFile([FromUri] string[] imgup)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
                {
                    // Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
                    var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file0"];

                    if (httpPostedFile != null)
                    {
                        // Validate the uploaded image(optional)

                        // Get the complete file path
                        var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/imgUpload"), httpPostedFile.FileName);

                        // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
                        httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
                    }
                }
            }
```

here its working fine. after uplaod the images in "imgUpload" folder its seen in excluded Format..please help to to solve this problem

Comment: what you mean by excluded format ?